# How to handle nullable parameters with HyprLinkr?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nullable, hyprlinkr

In ASP.NET Web API, I have a action method, that look like this:

```
    [GET("?{optionalValue:int?}"), HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Search(int? optionalValue = null)
```

How do I make a link, without the optionalValue parameter, using hyprlinkr?

Tried:

```
linker.GetUri<MyController>(c => c.Search(null).ToString()
```

which throws a NullReferenceException, the same does

```
linker.GetUri<MyController>(c => c.Search(new int?()).ToString()
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nullable seems to be supported with the latest version 1.0.1 of HyprLinkr, just use:

```
linker.GetUri<MyController>(c => c.Search(new int?()).ToString()
```